# Global name 'start' is not defined: Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the error "Global name 'start' is not defined" from the code snippet below. But the start(panel) call in displayImage(img) causes the image I want to see to be displayed in the GUI; without it no image shows up; it must be doing something. Yet I get the above error. I'm running this program in Ubuntu 12.04. BTW, I am new to both Python and Tkinter. Any way to get rid of this error? Edit: The adding of the image occurs during runtime with a button click that calls loadPicture(file).

```
import numpy as np
from Tkinter import *
import cv2 as cv
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import tkSimpleDialog as td
import math as mt
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


### General functions #############################################  

def raiseFileChooser():
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename()
    loadPicture(filename)

def loadPicture(file):
# set global variable for other uses
    global img
    img = cv.imread(file, 1) 
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
    displayImage(img, display1)   

def displayImage(image, panel):
    temp = Image.fromarray(image)
    bk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)
    bkLabel = Label(display1, image = bk)
    bkLabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    start(panel)

### Start App ###########################################

#### get GUI started
root = Tk()
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)  # so I can print entire arrays

### global variables ####################################
relStatus = StringVar()
relStatus.set(None)
text = StringVar()
filepath = StringVar()
filename = "No file chosen"
img = None
gsc = None
eStatus = StringVar()
eStatus.set(None)
display1 = None
display2 = None

### GUI #################################################
root.title("Picture Transformer")
root.geometry("700x600")

app = PanedWindow(root)
app.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

#Button Panel##############
buttonPanel = Frame(app,width=200, height = 400)
buttonPanel.pack(side=LEFT)

chooser = Button(buttonPanel, text="Choose File", height=1, width=9, command=raiseFileChooser)
chooser.pack()

#set up display panels ###########################
display1 = Frame(app, width=900, height=900, bg="#cccccc")
display1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "hw2.py", line 78, in raiseFileChooser
loadPicture(filename)
File "hw2.py", line 86, in loadPicture
start(panel)
NameError: global name 'start' is not defined
```

Comment: The error traceback must also show a line number. Can you please paste the full error stacktrace.

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with tkinter. Is the `start` function defined in `Tkinter` ?

Comment: Edited to add stacktrace.

Comment: Actually, I found that adding any text in the place of start() works. My guess is that start() is crashing the app; if the app were to continue the picture won't appear, for reasons I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong -- there is no global `start` function in your code. In fact, as near as I can tell, there's no `start` method anywhere, in any object that you are creating. Why do you think you should be calling a function named `start`? Is there some documentation somewhere that is telling you to do this?

My guess is, you're running in IDLE, and when you call the non-existent `start` function, the script crashes. When the script crashes it returns to IDLE, and whatever windows you had created to that point are now visible.

The most obvious problem you have in your code is that you aren't creating a root window. Somewhere early in your script, before you create any widgets or instances of `StringVar` you need to do something like this:

```
root = Tk()
```

Comment: I didn't post the whole code, I'll edit to put it in.

Comment: @Detroitteatime: The problem remains the same: you are calling a function that doesn't exist. Why do you think there's a function named "start" that should be called? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I must have copied it from some code somewhere without understanding it; the price of blindly copying. What is supposed to be used to show the image?

Comment: @Detroitteatime: there is no single thing you need to use in its place. If you create the widget, make the widget visible, and call `mainloop`, it will show up.

Comment: Does the fact that the image is loaded at runtime via a button click make a difference? I tried pacK() and the image didn't show up.

Comment: @Detroitteatime: you need to make sure the image reference isn't a local variable. You need to save a reference to the image in a class or global variable or the image will get destroyed when the local variable is garbage-collected. See http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Answer (score -1):

Try

`panel.start()`

Just a guess.Give a try, you might be able to solve the problem.

Comment: This definitely won't work. `panel` is an instance of a `Frame`, which has no method named `start`.

Answer (score -1):

root.mainloop() in the place of start() works.

Comment: It may seem to work, but that's not how you use `mainloop`. The code is already calling `mainloop` properly at the bottom of the script. Calling it again is not  how tkinter is designed to work.